# Using custom Typora themes with pandoc

Tags: pandoc, markdown

Is it possible to import custom Typora themes into pandoc?
We are using several custom themes which change the look and feel of the rendered Markdown code, but I am more familiar with pandoc. Rather than re-inventing the wheel, is it possible to reference or migrate the code over?
Thanks.

Comment: Does the Typora theme you want to use just consist of `css` files? If so, you can use the `--css` option to pandoc (as many times as needed), but I'm not sure the html will use the same tags and classes without a special filter, and for pdf output honoring the css, I think you would need to use an html-based pdf-engine rather than a latex based one, such as wkhtmltopdf, weasyprint or paged-cli (in which case your question becomes off-topic on this site).

Comment: Issues with pandoc or markdown may be on topic here, but only in connection with TeX and friends. I don't think Typora themes have any link whatsoever with TeX, but I might be wrong: can you please be more specific about your workflow?